# Reference to proof prints section instead

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have several theorems in a document with the proofs in the appendix. After some theorem, I want to refer to the proof and, using the `hyperref` package, I want to make the reference clickable to avoid scrolling.

However, adding a label to the proof and then referring to it (I am also using the `cleveref` package) refers and links to the respective section which holds the proof instead, in my example to the appendix.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

For an initution, see the proof.

For an intiution, see \cref{proof:some-theorem}.

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\begin{proof}[Proof of \Cref{thm:some-theorem}]
\label{proof:some-theorem}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the reference to print "proof" (or "proof of Theorem 1") instead, with the hyperlink also linking to the proof?

Comment: My mistake seems to be that I am trying to label/reference an unnumbered item/environment. Using `\hypertarget`  and `\hyperlink` works as a solution, though I still have to set the caption "proof" manually.

Comment: I am now using (apologies for the formatting):  
  
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}  
  
\begin{document}  
\section{Theorems}  
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:some-theorem}  
This is a theorem.  
\end{theorem}  
  
For an initution, see the proof.  
  
For an intiution, see the \hyperlink{proof:some-theorem}{proof}.  
  
\appendix  
\section{Proofs}  
\begin{proof}[Proof of \Cref{thm:some-theorem}]  
\hypertarget{proof:some-theorem}  
This is a proof.  
\end{proof}  
\end{document}

Comment: You don't have to add comments, you can edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make bidirectional links using the same label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{delayedproof}[1]
 {\begin{proof}[\raisedtarget{#1}Proof of \Cref{#1}]}
 {\end{proof}}
\newcommand{\raisedtarget}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\fontcharht\font`P}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#1}{}}%
}
\newcommand{\proofref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{proof}}

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

For an intuition, see the \proofref{thm:some-theorem}.

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\begin{delayedproof}{thm:some-theorem}
This is a proof.
\end{delayedproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture shows that the link “proof” refers to the correct proof. Raising the `\hypertarget` is needed or the link would point to the baseline of the proof's first line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was indicated by the O.P. already:

`proof` is a counterless environment, i.e. there is no counter connected to it, as such `\label` inside `proof` will grab the last `\@currentlabel`, this has been modified by `\refstepcounter{section}` in `\section{Proofs}`, so `\cref` reports `section` or `appendix for this.

My approach adds a `\prooflabel` that connects to the counter value of the theorem counter from the relevant label that is involved, such that Theorem 147 will provide Proof 147.

In order to simplify this, `\crtcrefcountervalue` (a new addition to `crossreftools` package) is applied and injected into the `proofcntr` counter.

I added `cleveref` names for the `proofcntr` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\usepackage{crossreftools}


%%% The following lines are not necessary with crossreftools v.0.8
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{crtcrefcountervalue}{%
\newcommand{\crt@crefundefinedcountervalue}{1977}
\newcommand{\crtrefundefinedcountervalue}[1]{\renewcommand{\crt@refundefinedcountervalue}{#1}}


\newcommand{\crtcrefcountervalue}[1]{%
  \crtcrefifundefinedlabel{#1}{%
    \crt@crefundefinedcountervalue%
  }{%
    \crtcrefnumber{#1}%
  }%
}
}{}

\makeatother



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{proofcntr}
\crefname{proofcntr}{proof}{proofs}
\Crefname{proofcntr}{Proof}{Proofs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prooflabel}{+m+m}{%
  \setcounter{proofcntr}{\numexpr\crtcrefcountervalue{#1}-1}%
  \refstepcounter{proofcntr}%
  \label{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Theorems}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:some-theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

For an intuition, see the proof.

For an intuition, see \cref{proof:some-theorem}, but with respect to \cref{thm:some-really-important-theorem} see the best proof ever: \cref{proof:some-really-important-theorem}


\begin{theorem}\label{thm:some-really-important-theorem}
Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin at the other end. 

Source: Anne Elk (Misses). 
\end{theorem}


\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\begin{proof}[Proof of \Cref{thm:some-theorem}]
\prooflabel{thm:some-theorem}{proof:some-theorem}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}


\begin{proof}[Proof of \Cref{thm:some-really-important-theorem}]
\prooflabel{thm:some-really-important-theorem}{proof:some-really-important-theorem}

The source is Anne Elk (Misses), that's enough ;-)
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work well unless you mix proofs of Lemmas and Theorems that have different counters.

Comment: There's a pretty easy fix to my previous comment: Define a separate counter for each type of result: 
`\newcounter{theoremproofcntr}`
`\newcounter{lemmaproofcntr}`

Modify `\prooflabel` as
`\NewDocumentCommand{\prooflabel}{o +m+m}{%`
`\setcounter{#1proofcntr}{\numexpr\crtcrefcountervalue{#2}-1}%`
`\refstepcounter{#1proofcntr}%`
`\label{#3}%`
`}`

And label a proof of a theorem like `\prooflabel[theorem]{result:pythagorean theorem}{proof:pythagorean theorem}`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  \phantomsection\label{theorem:main}
  This is true.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  \phantomsection\label{proof:main-theorem}
  Obvious.
\end{proof}

The \hyperref[proof:main-theorem]{proof} of
the \hyperref[theorem:main]{theorem} is obvious.

\end{document}
```